# Design a tool for calculated the Power BI reports page load time automatically

Tags: powerbi

> I have a hundreds of power bi reports. Now i want calculate the page
>   load time of each report daily. Please anyone can suggest a approach
>   to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Write an application to enumerate over workspaces and reports, embed them and measure the time till `rendered` [event](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Handling-Events) is raised.